# Threshold in Sharepoint Dashboard Designer For Percentage KPI

Tags: sql, sharepoint, report, ssas, data-warehouse

I have got a SSAS cube, that has a KPI which has a Value as a percentage. I also have a Goal which is also the target percentage to keep the Value below.

I create  the KPI fine, but when I import it into the dashboard designer and set the scoring pattern and indicator ( I used tick, exlamation mark, cross - which gives 2 thresholds). It always shows the tick even though its way over the goal.

I have set it to be that decreasing is better and the banding method is "Band by stated score", but it always shows on the scorecard as being On Target.

This is the threshold I currently have.

[image]

Is it something to do with having the goal as a percentage? Can anyone explain how Dashboard Designer thresholds work with percentages please??

Update : Seemed to get it to work by setting the thresholds against the actual values in stead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer to this for anyone who wants to know still. 
I did indeed need the "Band by stated score" banding method, the thing I was missing was where does the score come from? This is not immediately obvious but it is in the "Specify the worst value" section when editing the banding settings.

This needs to be set correctly against the threshold values.

Answer (score 0):

The percentage works in terms of decimal.
0 = 0%
0.5 = 50%
1 = 100%

In your scenario, you can use -0.01, 0.8, 1, 1.01

Thanks,
Merin